# How to make UI components disappear when a certain RadioButton is selected

Tags: android, radio-button, visibility

I have created a layout xml file where I have two `RadioButton`s.

By default, `RadioButton` 1 is selected and I am displaying a `DatePicker` component on the screen but when the user selects `RadioButton`2 the `DatePicker` should disappear from the screen.

How can I handle the scenario? Should I make the change in layout / Java code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is actually very simple.

Get a reference of your `RadioGroup` and your `DatePicker`. Implement an `OnCheckedChangeListener` for the `RadioGroup` and check which `RadioButton` was checked in there.

If `RadioButton` A was checked set the visibility on your `DatePicker` to visible and if `RadioButton` B was checked set the visibility to `gone` or `invisible` depending on your requirement.

As an example.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private RadioGroup choice;
    private DatePicker datePicker;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        choice = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.choice);
        datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.date_picker);

        choice.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
            new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch(checkedId) {
                    case R.id.radio_button_a:
                        datePicker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case R.id.radio_button_b:
                        datePicker.setVisibility(View.GONE);                    
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

In theory it should be something like that.