# building a basic android app with fragments

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, dialog, fragment

I want to write an android app that starts the main activity which only shows an animation and then after 1 second text hello is printed next to him and only stays there for 2 seconds.  afterwards new text appears and stays for 4 seconds.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to use toast or what to show the message?

If the answer is Toast, you can try this method!

The "msg" parameter is your message and the "tempo" parameter is for how long you want the message to be shown (in MS). I hope it helps, friend! :)

```
public static void Msg(Activity activity, String msg, int tempo)
{
    final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(activity, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

    //for how long the message will be shown
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            toast.cancel();
        }
    }, tempo);
}
```

Comment: Great!  Also if I want a TextView and EditText box to appear after the second Toast message runs, how can I do this?  and if possible I want a Toast message to be posted after the user inputs text--and the toast message will depend on the users input.

Comment: You can make your activity with invisible components and, once you show the second Toast message, you make them appear. Check out this link for some extra help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850238/how-to-make-ui-components-disappear-when-a-certain-radiobutton-is-selected